# mass assignment on [App\comment] in laravel

Tags: laravel, store

trying to add a comment in my blog , so i got this new error :

```
Add [body] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\comment].
```

this is thr controller :

```
public function store  (blog $getid)
{
    comment::create([
        'body' =>request('body'),
        'blog_id'=> $getid->id
    ]);

     return view('blog');
}
```

and this is the form :

```
<form method="POST" action="/blog/{{$showme->id}}/store" >
   @csrf
   <label> Commentaire </label> </br>
   <textarea name="body" id="" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea> </br>
   <button type="submit"> Ajouter commentaire</button>
</form>
```

web.php :

```
Route::post('blog/{getid}/store', 'commentcontroller@store');
```

Comment: just add `'body'` to `$fillable` array in `App\comment` Model !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid filling in any given property, `Laravel` has mass asignment protection. The properties you want to be filled should be in the `$fillable` property on the model.

```
class Comment {
    $fillable = ['body', 'blog_id'];
}
```

**Bonus**

For keeping up with standards. You should not name your classes in lower case, it should be `Blog` and `Comment`, both in `PHP` code and in file name.

Id should not be filled but associated, so they will be loaded properly on the model. So imagine your `Comment` model having the blog relationship.

```
class Comment {
    public function blog() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
    }
}
```

You should assign it instead. Where you would get the Blog by using Model binding, therefor you should name the parameter $blog so the binding will work. Additionally using Request dependency injected, is also a good approach.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request, Blog $blog) {
    $comment = new Comment(['body' => $request->input('body')]);
    $comment->blog()->associate($blog);
    $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: A lot of bonus related cleanup, don't have to master all, but is a pointer in the direction where i would expect most Laravel developers to end up at some point.